# Gradient background in tabBar

Tags: ios, swift

I've subclassed the `TabBarController` and is then trying to make gradient background. however it does not seem to work. nothing is shown. i'm by the way using the [Hue](https://github.com/hyperoslo/Hue) framework

```
    let tabBarGradient = [UIColor.redColor(), UIColor.blackColor()].gradient { gradient in
        gradient.frame = self.tabBar.frame
        gradient.startPoint = CGPointMake(0,0.5)
        gradient.endPoint = CGPointMake(1,0.5)

        return gradient
    }

    self.tabBar.layer.addSublayer(tabBarGradient)
```

Comment: no i dont forgot to set color?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

in your CustomTabBarController, write this code:

```
import UIKit

class GradientTabBarController: UITabBarController {

    let layerGradient = CAGradientLayer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        layerGradient.colors = [UIColor.red.cgColor, UIColor.yellow.cgColor]
        layerGradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5)
        layerGradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0.5)
        layerGradient.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.bounds.width, height: view.bounds.height)
        self.tabBar.layer.insertSublayer(layerGradient, at: 0)
    }
}
```

You can see the gradient in your tabbar like this:

[image]

And the storyboard you assign CustomTabBarController to your TabBarController in the storyboard.

[image]

Comment: You'd better use insertSublayer(layerGradient, at: 0) instead of addSublayer(layerGradient) because addSublayer adds gradient layer above your tabs and they're becoming invisible

Answer (score 8):

Use

```
    self.tabBar.layer.insertSublayer(layerGradient, at:0)
```

instead of

```
    self.tabBar.layer.addSublayer(layerGradient)
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48853918/4449202

Answer (score 2):

To expand on Khuong's answer, the above won't work for a Y gradient because it is using the `view.Frame` to set the width and height for the `layerGradient.Frame`. `view` is the container view and is larger than the tab bar. Instead when setting the `layerGradient.Frame` use the `tabBar.Frame`:

```
 layerGradient.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tabBar.bounds.width,height: tabBar.bounds.height)
```