# UITabBarItems not showing up after subclassing UITabBarController

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, subclass

I've been trying to add a gradient to the UITabBar in my app. After a few failed attempts I followed the steps from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35770341/gradient-background-in-tabbar) and the. gradient now works, but the UITabBarItems are invisible (although they all work). How can I make sure that both the gradient and the UIITabBarItems are visible?

```
class GradientTabBarController: UITabBarController {

let layerGradient = CAGradientLayer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("custom tabbar loaded")
    layerGradient.colors = [UIColor(named: "tabBarGradient1")?.cgColor, UIColor(named: "tabBarGradient2")?.cgColor]
    layerGradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x:0.5, y: 0)
    layerGradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1)
    layerGradient.frame = tabBar.bounds
    self.tabBar.layer.addSublayer(layerGradient)
 } 
}
```

what it looks like in the simulator:
[image: Simulator view]

The missing Icons (view from Interface Builder)
[image: IB view]

Answer (score 3):

What you're doing is not supported. However, if you're going to do it, you need to put the gradient layer *behind* the tab bar items. You are putting it in *front* of the tab bar items:

```
 self.tabBar.layer.addSublayer(layerGradient)
```

You need to say something more like:

```
 self.tabBar.layer.insertSublayer(layerGradient, at:0)
```

The idea is to put the layer *behind* the tab bar items. But exactly what number to use, I'm not sure; you'll have to experiment, and I don't guarantee the robustness of any such action going forward. And it might not even work at all, because the tab bar items are not views.

The *correct* way to make a custom background for a tab bar is to make a UIView displaying your gradient, and set it as the tab bar's [`backgroundImage`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbar/1623469-backgroundimage). Why don't you do this the correct supported way instead of your hacky unsupported way? You should *use* the framework, not *fight* the framework.

Comment: It's because I didn't know the correct way to do it. Thanks for the suggestion though. I'll try that.